# How to leverage a DB query with views?

Tags: views

I have three things:

- A user (User entity)
- A league (Node)
- A league entry (Node, with a numerical field for time and a noderef field to a league)

A user can create a league entry node, and set a time value and a node reference to a league node.

I want to produce a view that takes the league node id as an argument, and produces a table row for each user that has submitted a league entry node. The columns will be the user name, a user field that states the user's team, and finally, for every league entry node raised by them as author, that contains a node reference to the current league nid, a sum of the matching league entries numerical fields.

Now as you can imagine, doing this in views is very problematic because of aggregation issues on a single field; so a simpler alternative is to simple create a new DB table that stores the data I want to display in distinct fields.

So if I have a DB table like:

username, league, total of league entry nodes time value so far

How can I get this info into views so I can take advantage of table display, column sorting, and all that good stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways of doing this. You can create an [entity](https://www.drupal.org/node/1261744). This requires the writing of a custom module to do so. Entities can be challenging if you have never done them before.

Another way and slightly simpler (still requires a custom module). Is to use the [Views API](https://api.drupal.org/api/views). The first thing you would implement is [hook_views_data()](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_data/7). This is a [really good example](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21commerce%21modules%21order%21includes%21views%21commerce_order.views.inc/7) of hook_views_data borrowed from Drupal Commerce.

Lastly, there are some modules out there that might help. One of them is [Schema Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/schema_views).

Comment: That's loads of entrypoints, thank you! I can go from here :)